# FTP: wildcard downloading

Tags: linux, ftp, wget, curl, curlftpfs

I am trying to download a file with name ending with *.csv

The problem is complicated by the fact that this *.csv contains in directory of unknown name:

eg. Sometimes it would be

2015->Date 29:10:20:10->One.csv

Or

2015->Date 27:10:21:10->Two.csv

How do I use Wget or ANYTHING(in Linux) that does wildcard directory matching, as well as wildcard file matching?